# I'm looking for a Python module or codes to permutate an asymmetric matrix into triangular form

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, permutation, symmetric, triangular

I have an asymmetric matrix.

```
    A   B   C   D
A   0   0   1   0
B   1   0   0   1
C   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   1   0
```

I'm trying to switch rows and columns to make it into triangular form.

Like:

```
    C   A   D   B
C   0   1   1   0
A   0   0   1   1
D   0   0   0   1
B   0   0   1   0
```

Someone gave some codes which is made by VBA and used in Microsoft Excel. According to the note in those code, I found a paper ("Algorithm 529:Permutations to Block Triangular Form.") published by 1978 which was made in Fortran. I also found a paper (Implementation of Tarjan's Algorithm for the Block Triangularization of a Matrix) which might describe the concept.

I look at numpy but I didn't find such function. I'm wondering whether there is a ready-made module in some packages to complete this process. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I don't see triangular matrix in example.

Problem is [NP-complete](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01189621/document), so you can just generate all permutations of rows and columns until triangular matrix is reached. (Or try to implement algo from the linked article)

---

Article name for record

```
Obtaining a Triangular Matrix by Independent Row-Column Permutations
Guillaume Fertin, Irena Rusu, Stéphane Vialette
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I found this paper before but just viewed it. I'll read it carefully. I used the word "triangular" along with the book. I just want to change row or column simultaniously then move as many "1"s as possible above the diagnal. I delibarately designed an interlocked block in the example which is placed at lower right corner after permutation. Thanks again for your information.